# How to animate the cursor in text box when focused?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like in the gif. On selecting the search box the cursor animates and goes to the left. Can we animate the cursor when focused?

[image]

Dribbble :https://dribbble.com/shots/1869887

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979394/animation-synching-cursor-and-highlight

Comment: @Fareya But  in my case the cursor will have to wait until the animation gets over.